# Oracle changing a date of birth to age

Tags: oracle, date, formatting

I need to convert a date of birth to current age  in years using a column Dob in date format and system date but populate the result in the dob column.
The date format is dd-mm-yy.
I have tried using to_char and to_number functions to subtract from sys date

Comment: Please post what you tried so far, together with some sample data and needed result. For example, do you only need years as an integer? qith decimals? ...

Comment: A `date` column has no "format". Something like `(sysdate - dob) / 365` is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you only need years and that your `dob` column is a `date`, you may need:

```
select dob, floor(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
from yourTable
```

For example:

```
with yourTable(dob) as (
    select date '2000-02-01' from dual union all
    select date '2000-02-02' from dual union all
    select date '2000-01-31' from dual 
    )
select dob, floor(months_between(sysdate, dob) / 12) age
from yourTable
```

gives:

```
DOB               AGE
---------- ----------
2000-02-01         18
2000-02-02         17
2000-01-31         18

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need years, months and days for the date_of_birth column. You can do the below.

```
select sysdate,
  date_of_birth,
  trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth) / 12) as years,
  trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth) -
    (trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth) / 12) * 12)) as months,
  trunc(sysdate) - add_months(date_of_birth, trunc(months_between(sysdate,date_of_birth))) as days
from table_name;
```